# Combining search and checkbox javascript filter on table

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, filter, html-table

I have a search filter and checkbox filter on an html table that are both working well, but they work independently. I would like to be able to check a category, and then use the search box within that category. Right now, if I start searching, the checkbox resets and vice versa.

I think there may be two ways to do this - either update the GetElement functions to only fetch what is displayed, or to combine the two if/else statements into one. But I'm self-taught and this is all new to me so I'm having trouble writing the correct code!

```js
  function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
      if (td) {
        txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  } 
src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"

  // Select cluster
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
      var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
      var checked = $(this)[0].checked;
      $("tr").each(function() {
        if ($(this).find("td:eq(1)").html() !== undefined && $(this).find("td:eq(1)").html().includes(inputValue.toString())) {
          if (checked) {
            $(this).show(); // slice by n numbers here
          } else {
            $(this).hide();
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });

function checkedAll() {
  console.log("All")
  var elements = this.form.getElementsByTagName('input');
  console.log(elements)
  // iterate and change status
  for (var i = elements.length; i--;) {
    if (elements[i].type == 'checkbox') {
      console.log(this)
      elements[i].checked = this.checked;
      $(elements[i]).trigger("change");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table#myTable {
  width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<!-- SEARCH -->

<h3>Search by keyword or phrase:</h3>
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Start typing to filter the table below" style="width:100%; transform: none;">


<!-- CHECKMARKS -->


<form action="" method="post" name="frm1" id="frm1">

  <h3>Filter by category:</h3>

  <label class="clickable">
<input type="checkbox" name="cluster_ids" id="cluster_ids" onclick="checkedAll.call(this);" checked /> Select all</label><br>

  <div style="float:left; width:33%; min-width:200px;">
    <label class="clickable">
<input value="For attorneys" type="checkbox" name="cluster_ids" checked/> For attorneys</label><br>

    <label class="clickable">
<input value="For clinicians" type="checkbox" name="cluster_ids" checked/> For clinicians</label><br>

    <label class="clickable">
<input value="For patients and families" type="checkbox" name="cluster_ids" checked/> For patients and families</label><br>


    <!-- TABLE -->

    <table id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <th>
          <h1>Resource</h1>
        </th>
        <th>
          <h1>Category</h1>
        </th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <h3>20 things patients can do to help prevent medical errors</h3>
          <p>Information for patients from the Agency for Healthcare Research and Quality (AHRQ)</p>
        </td>
        <td class="topic-column">For patients and families</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <h3>Best practices for attorneys representing patients using CARe</h3>
          <p>How lawyers can best support patients during the CARe process</p>
        </td>

        <td class="topic-column">For attorneys</td>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>Clinician CARe communication algorithm</h3>
            <p>Flow chart with examples of what to say and what not to say during conversations with patients and families</p>
          </td>
          <td class="topic-column">For clinicians</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>Guidelines for handling medical adverse events: Enhancing safety through candid communication</h3>
            <p>Covers the seven aspects of response to adverse events: initial response, truth-telling, apologies, mediation, root cause analysis, compensation, and reporting</p>
          </td>
          <td class="topic-column">For clinicians</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>Handout for patients</h3>
            <p>A patient-focused flyer that explains the elements of CARe</p>
          </td>
          <td class="topic-column">For patients and families</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: You rather use snippet to make live exemple

Answer (score 1):

**Let us see what went wrong:**

> `myFunction` actually search on every row but as per your need it should
> search on only selected category
>
> inside document ready also logic was incorrect `$(this).find("td:eq(1)").html().includes(inputValue.toString())`

**How we can fix it:**

> We have a function `getCheckedItems` which return an array currently
> selected checked box value I.e category
>
> `getCheckedItems` call form inside document ready to show row for only
> selected category. Document ready code is also been simplified
>
> inside `myFunction` also checking same logic filter look only on
> selected category return by  `getCheckedItems` function

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
     function getCheckedItems() {
        
        let checkboxValues = [];
        
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(index) {
            
            let inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
            
            if( $(this).is(':checked') && inputValue ){
                
                checkboxValues.push(inputValue);
            }
        });

        return checkboxValues;
    }

    function myFunction() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            let htmlCategory = $(tr[i]).find("td:eq(1)").html();
            if (td) {
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 && getCheckedItems().includes(htmlCategory)) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {

            $("tr").each(function() {

                let htmlCategory = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").html();
                if(getCheckedItems().includes(htmlCategory)) {
                    $(this).show(); // slice by n numbers here
                }
                else {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
        });
    });

    function checkedAll() {
        console.log("All")
        var elements = this.form.getElementsByTagName('input');
        console.log(elements)
        // iterate and change status
        for (var i = elements.length; i--;) {
            if (elements[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                console.log(this)
                elements[i].checked = this.checked;
                $(elements[i]).trigger("change");
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    table#myTable {
            width: 800px;
    }
```

#### Search by keyword or phrase:

```
<h3>Filter by category:</h3>

<label class="clickable">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cluster_ids" id="cluster_ids" onclick="checkedAll.call(this);" checked /> Select all</label><br>

<div style="float:left; width:33%; min-width:200px;">
    <label class="clickable">
        <input value="For attorneys" type="checkbox" name="cluster_ids" checked/> For attorneys</label><br>

    <label class="clickable">
        <input value="For clinicians" type="checkbox" name="cluster_ids" checked/> For clinicians</label><br>

    <label class="clickable">
        <input value="For patients and families" type="checkbox" name="cluster_ids" checked/> For patients and families</label><br>


    <!-- TABLE -->

    <table id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <h1>Resource</h1>
            </th>
            <th>
                <h1>Category</h1>
            </th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3>20 things patients can do to help prevent medical errors</h3>
                <p>Information for patients from the Agency for Healthcare Research and Quality (AHRQ) apologies</p>
            </td>
            <td class="topic-column">For patients and families</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3>Best practices for attorneys representing patients using CARe</h3>
                <p>How lawyers can best support patients during the CARe process</p>
            </td>

            <td class="topic-column">For attorneys</td>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3>Clinician CARe communication algorithm</h3>
                <p>Flow chart with examples of what to say and what not to say during conversations with patients and families</p>
            </td>
            <td class="topic-column">For clinicians</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3>Guidelines for handling medical adverse events: Enhancing safety through candid communication</h3>
                <p>Covers the seven aspects of response to adverse events: initial response, truth-telling, apologies, mediation, root cause analysis, compensation, and reporting</p>
            </td>
            <td class="topic-column">For clinicians</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3>Handout for patients</h3>
                <p>A patient-focused flyer that explains the elements of CARe</p>
            </td>
            <td class="topic-column">For patients and families</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: Maybe it will work. However not saying what you did makes this answer useless for anyone else with the same problem.

Comment: @Wimanicesir thanks for your comments, i do check from my side and its full fill what question asking for. and definitely it will work for every one else with  slimier need. kindly inform what make you to give a negative vote so that i can be more careful before posting answer.

Comment: Well, the other answer should give you some insights. You should say in words what went wrong and how you improved/fixed it. This can be a list like the other answer or in the code as comments. Another person is not going to have the exact same code but could have a similar mistake and so he can learn from your approach.

Comment: Also, when possible, it's preferred to have a working example so everyone can verify instantly whether it works like expected.

Comment: @Wimanicesir thank you so much for your kind suggestion. Now onward i will try to include what went wrong and how you improved/fixed it also try to post snippet run code

Comment: Last tip, my downvote is now locked until you edit the question, so even if I want to withdraw the downvote, I can't.

Comment: @Wimanicesir i have updated my answer as per your suggestion. Please give me a up vote if it is ok and you like it

Comment: Almost perfect, next time, remember the small working snippet! Upvote given. Thanks for learning!

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have made simple twist to your code.

1. I have added `hidden-cat` to `tr` when it is hidden from checkbox. So, that we can know that those items are hidden by checkbox.
2. I changed your `myFunction()` and bind `#myInput` with input event instead of keyup so that I can handle copy paste also.
3. Also added `hidden` class so that we can know that item is hidden from search field and we can show that when use press backspace or remove the search keyword.
4. Similarly, checked if undefined by `if(inputValue !== undefined) {}` in your `// Select cluster` section.

**Note: This is a just proof of concept example.** *You might need to work on optimization and exception handling.*

```js
$("#myInput").off("input").on("input", function() {
  var inputValue = $(this).val();
  if (inputValue === "") {
    $("tr:not(.header, .hidden-cat)").removeClass('hidden').show();
    return;
  }
  $("tr:not(.header,.hidden-cat)").addClass('hidden').hide();
  $("#myTable").find("tr:not(.header, .hidden-cat)").each(function() {
    let $this = $(this);
    if ($this.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
      $this.removeClass('hidden').show();
    }
  });
});
src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"

// Select cluster
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
    var checked = $(this)[0].checked;
    $("tr").each(function() {
      if (inputValue !== undefined) {
        if ($(this).find("td:eq(1)").html() !== undefined && $(this).find("td:eq(1)").html().includes(inputValue.toString())) {
          if (checked) {
            $(this).removeClass("hidden-cat").show(); // slice by n numbers here
          } else {
            $(this).addClass("hidden-cat").hide();
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
});

function checkedAll() {
  //console.log("All")
  var elements = this.form.getElementsByTagName('input');
  //console.log(elements)
  // iterate and change status
  for (var i = elements.length; i--;) {
    if (elements[i].type == 'checkbox') {
      //console.log(this)
      elements[i].checked = this.checked;
      $(elements[i]).trigger("change");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table#myTable {
  width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- SEARCH -->

<h3>Search by keyword or phrase:</h3>
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Start typing to filter the table below" style="width:100%; transform: none;">


<!-- CHECKMARKS -->


<form action="" method="post" name="frm1" id="frm1">

  <h3>Filter by category:</h3>

  <label class="clickable">
<input type="checkbox" name="cluster_ids" id="cluster_ids" onclick="checkedAll.call(this);" checked /> Select all</label><br>

  <div style="float:left; width:33%; min-width:200px;">
    <label class="clickable">
<input value="For attorneys" type="checkbox" name="cluster_ids" checked/> For attorneys</label><br>

    <label class="clickable">
<input value="For clinicians" type="checkbox" name="cluster_ids" checked/> For clinicians</label><br>

    <label class="clickable">
<input value="For patients and families" type="checkbox" name="cluster_ids" checked/> For patients and families</label><br>


    <!-- TABLE -->

    <table id="myTable">
      <tr class="header">
        <th>
          <h1>Resource</h1>
        </th>
        <th>
          <h1>Category</h1>
        </th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <h3>20 things patients can do to help prevent medical errors</h3>
          <p>Information for patients from the Agency for Healthcare Research and Quality (AHRQ)</p>
        </td>
        <td class="topic-column">For patients and families</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <h3>Best practices for attorneys representing patients using CARe</h3>
          <p>How lawyers can best support patients during the CARe process</p>
        </td>

        <td class="topic-column">For attorneys</td>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>Clinician CARe communication algorithm</h3>
            <p>Flow chart with examples of what to say and what not to say during conversations with patients and families</p>
          </td>
          <td class="topic-column">For clinicians</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>Guidelines for handling medical adverse events: Enhancing safety through candid communication</h3>
            <p>Covers the seven aspects of response to adverse events: initial response, truth-telling, apologies, mediation, root cause analysis, compensation, and reporting</p>
          </td>
          <td class="topic-column">For clinicians</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>Handout for patients</h3>
            <p>A patient-focused flyer that explains the elements of CARe</p>
          </td>
          <td class="topic-column">For patients and families</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```